# Return JsonResult with apostrophes

Tags: javascript, c#, json

As far as I can tell, I am getting a parser error because some of the data I am returning contains apostrophes.

**Error I'm getting:**

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at Object.parse (native) at jQuery.parseJSON...

**My javascript:**

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    hospitalDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Hospital/GetHospitals",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET"
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        ProviderId: { type: "number" },
                        Name: { type: "string" },
                        Active: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            },
            errors: "errorMsg"
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        error: function (e) {
            toastr.options = {
                "positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width"
            };
            toastr.error('There was an error:' + e.errors, 'Uh Oh!');
            this.cancelChanges();
        },
        serverPaging: false,
        serverFiltering: false,
        serverSorting: false
    }),
})
```

**Controller JsonResult:**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetHospitals()
{
    var hospitals = hospitalService.GetAllHospitals();
    return Json(hospitals, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

As I mentioned above, I believe I'm getting the parser error because some of my data contains apostrophes.
For example, `Name` might include the string `Women and Children's Hospital`

I'm still new to MVC/C# and Json so I'm not sure how to go about solving this. Is there a way to escape all of the apostrophes? Or is there something else I should be doing.

Let me know if anything I said is not clear. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the JSON result?

Comment: You could try using html encoding on the apostrophes, which should convert them to `&apos;`.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is a duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042302/serializing-strings-containing-apostrophes-with-json-net

Comment: *"As far as I can tell, I am getting a parser error because some of the data I am returning contains apostrophes."* If the data is serialized properly to JSON, then that shouldn't be a problem. Could the error be elsewhere? What does `kendo.data.DataSource` do with the data?

Comment: @maniak1982 That worked, thanks!

Comment: You might want to try using JsonNetResult instead of JsonResult. http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/10/16/asp-net-mvc-and-json-net

Comment: Probably this, already asked on Stackoverflow, will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931237/how-can-i-return-a-well-formatted-201-with-express

Comment: Please post the actual JSON output. You can get that by navigating to the `/Hospital/GetHospitals` route in your browser. The answers are terrible workaround that make no sense. Something else is wrong here.

Comment: @poke For some reason when I navigate to the correct URL in the browser it's just a blank page. But it is the right URL because that action gets hit when I debug it and navigate there.

Comment: What does it show when you show the source of that page in your browser? Is there still no output?

Comment: @poke Yeah still nothing. I am running Telerik Fiddler as well and it shows nothing is being returned when I go there.

Comment: Then you know why the JavaScript is messing up there: It’s trying to parse nothing as JSON.

Comment: Look in the developer tools of your browser. There should be a "Network" tab or something similar which should show what was returned from the service call.

Comment: @poke What could be causing that issue? When debugging if I hover over  `hospitals` it shows the data is there. But obviously it's not being returned as JSON.

@MikeMcCaughan The response I get is "Failed to load response data"

Comment: What version of ASP.NET MVC are you using? Do you get any logging output on the server side?

Comment: @poke Yep I didn't even think to check the logs. I'm getting the error: Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

Comment: @Quiver Thanks!  I wrote the comments as an answer if you would like to mark it resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the user poke I was able to resolve this issue. It ended up not being a problem with the apostrophes but rather that the JSON Result that I was trying to return was longer than the max value set by default in MVC.

I was able to use this answer to solve my problem: [Can I set an unlimited length for maxJsonLength in web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config/7207539#7207539)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape those apostrophes first by using `str.Replace("'", "\\'")`. to replace occurrences of `"'"` with `"\'"`

Comment: Can you explain why? Why exactly does this error occur?

Comment: AFAIK some JSON parsers will interpret both single and double quotes that are not preceded by a \ as the end of the JSON object. This has worked for me in the past

Comment: Which parsers are those? Why not use `JSON.parse` in that case, which doesn't have that problem?

Comment: Thanks! Both the solution that maniak1982 offered and this one work.

Comment: @Quiver if this was helpful don't forget to mark as answer. Thanks :)

Comment: @Quiver: These are workarounds, not solutions. There shouldn't be an issue with having `'` in your data, otherwise JSON itself would be completely broken (and it's not).

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing that the problem is related to the apostrophes, because the json serializer should escape them if needed. Anyway, to replace them better do it before serializing your object's collection.

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetHospitals()
{
    var hospitals = hospitalService.GetAllHospitals();

    // Replaces the apostrophes from the hospital name
    foreach(var hospital in hospitals) {
        hospital.Name = hospital.Name.Replace("'", ""); 
    }

    return Json(hospitals, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

In this way JSON will be returned without the aphostrophes on the name.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using html encoding on the apostrophes, which should convert them to `&apos;`

Usually this is a problem with the `JSON.parse()` call or any functions that rely on it, as it doesn't escape apostrophes or quotation marks.  It should be fine with HTML entities, however.

If you're accustomed to using `eval()` to parse JSON, you won't have seen it.  But you should really use a JSON parser for reasons outlined here:

http://www.json.org/js.html

Microsoft's ASP.NET implementation of HTML Encoding is described here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx